# syntax error with methods inside functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I created an app with create-react-app, and I wanted to write a functional component, but I am getting syntax errors with methods. i took a capture with the errors

[image: error at the level of methods]

Comment: Don't post your code as images, please!

Comment: Read [ask] for more information about posting images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`delete` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) That's why you can't name your function `delete` – try something else (for a handler, `handleDelete`).

Either way, you need to do

```
const handleDelete = () => {...};
```

and not just

```
handleDelete = () => {...};
```